# Exclude product pages from 'woocommerce_before_main_content' function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My current code in `functions.php` inserts an image before the woocommerce content which I'm happy with but I don't want the image to appear on the product pages, how do I go about excluding them?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', function() {
echo '<a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=1831" target="_blank">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/promotion-banner.jpg"></a>';
}, 18, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Adding `if (is_front_page())` before `echo` line does the job:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', function() {
if (is_front_page())
echo '<a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=1831" target="_blank">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/promotion-banner.jpg"></a>';
}, 18, 0 );
```